# Xcode 12 failed to build cocoa pods - generate umbrella header

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, ios14, xcode12

When updating to XCode 12, the project stopped working. Not able to build the project. Number of errors occurred stating failed to build cocoa pods generate umbrella header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, follow the below steps

1. Go to pods

[image]

2. Select build settings
3. Search **quoted**
4. Set value of **Quoted include in Framework Header** to **No**

[image]

5. Clean and Run the project.